# XML not creating correctly: content is empty

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I tried this code to convert XSD to XML file using java. The output XML file is blank.

**This is the java code:-**

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.apache.xerces.xs.XSModel;
import org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.inst2xsd.util.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;

import jlibs.xml.sax.XMLDocument;
import jlibs.xml.xsd.XSContentModel;
import jlibs.xml.xsd.XSInstance;
import jlibs.xml.xsd.XSParser;

public class xsdconv {

     public static void main(String[] pArgs) {
            try {
                String filename ="C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\out.xsd";
                // instance.

                final Document doc = loadXsdDocument(filename);

                            //Find the docs root element and use it to find the targetNamespace
                final org.w3c.dom.Element rootElem = doc.getDocumentElement();
                String targetNamespace = null;
                if (rootElem != null && rootElem.getNodeName().equals("xsd:schema")) 
                           {
                    targetNamespace = rootElem.getAttribute("root");
                }


                            //Parse the file into an XSModel object
                XSModel xsModel = new XSParser().parse(filename);

                            //Define defaults for the XML generation
                XSInstance instance = new XSInstance();
                instance.minimumElementsGenerated = 1;
                instance.maximumElementsGenerated = 1;
                instance.generateDefaultAttributes = true;
                instance.generateOptionalAttributes = true;
                instance.maximumRecursionDepth = 0;
                instance.generateAllChoices = true;
                instance.showContentModel = true;
                instance.generateOptionalElements = true;

                            //Build the sample xml doc
                            //Replace first param to XMLDoc with a file input stream to write to file
                QName rootElement = new QName(targetNamespace, "root");
                XMLDocument sampleXml = new XMLDocument(new StreamResult("C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/out.xml"), true, 4, null);

            } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) 
                    {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public static Document loadXsdDocument(String inputName) {
            final String filename = inputName;

            final DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance(); 
            factory.setValidating(false); 
            factory.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
            factory.setIgnoringComments(true);
            Document doc = null;

            try {
                final DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
                final File inputFile = new File(filename);
                doc = builder.parse(inputFile);
                System.out.println(filename);
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                // throw new ContentLoadException(msg);
            }

            return doc;
        }
}
```

**the sample XSD file is :-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="root">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="header" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xsd:normalizedString"/>
        <xsd:element name="row" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xsd:string"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

*So  I want to extract header and row information from it. It is creating blank XML file . What am I missing in this code ?
Parsing is working fine I guess.*

**EDIT**
This is the info in XSD file and I want XSD file  to create XML same like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<root>
  <header>Symbol</header>
    <row>NIFTY 50</row>
    <row>LUPIN</row>
    <header>Open</header>
    <row>9,670.35</row>
    <row>1,082.90</row>
</root>
```

Comment: What are you expecting in the xml file?

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis something like this  :- <root><header>..</header><row>..</row><row>..</row><header>...</header><row>..</row><row>..</row></root> . I want to extract element name="header" and "row"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't populated the XML file. You could add after the line:

```
XMLDocument sampleXml = new XMLDocument(new StreamResult("C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/out.xml"), true, 4, null);
```

something like:

```
sampleXml.startDocument();{
    sampleXml.startElement("root");{
        sampleXml.addElement("header", "Symbol");
        sampleXml.addElement("row","NIFTY 50");
        sampleXml.addElement("row","LUPIN");
        sampleXml.addElement("header", "Open");
        sampleXml.addElement("row","9,670.35");
        sampleXml.addElement("row","1,082.90");
    }
    sampleXml.endElement("root");
}
sampleXml.endDocument();
```

Or any other content you prefer as a default setup.

Comment: the `headerValue` and `rowValue` should be initialized to null ?

Comment: I just gave it as an example. You can provide an appropriate value for the variable if you want. As far as I understood your question, you just wanted to see something in the XML file - so use the values you wish to see. If you want to see empty/null values, you can use those.

Comment: Ok let me add values of xml file which is already there in XSD "header" and "row". I am adding this on question EDIT.

Comment: I edited the example to look like the default file you requested. Could you try it and see if it leads to the XML you want?

Comment: Thank you so much , What if there are multiple data ?

Comment: You can create the XML you want by using the startElement+EndElement with addAttribute in any legal order (legal - according to the XSD). You can use loops with different values, you can even read some values from somewhere else and use them in your file. If this example helped your question, may I kindly ask you accept it as an answer?

Comment: Hi, according to your answer , the output is only of 1 line :- `<root header="Open" row="1,082.90"/>` something am I missing out.

Comment: Throwing Exception:- `Exception in thread "main" org.xml.sax.SAXException: expected </ns:Symbol>
 at jlibs.xml.sax.XMLDocument.endElement(XMLDocument.java:301)
 at jlibs.xml.sax.XMLDocument.endElement(XMLDocument.java:306)
 at csvconverter.xsdconv.main(xsdconv.java:61)`

Comment: perhaps addElement will be better for this case? I corrected the example. Can you please check?

Comment: Always happy to help!